# How to separate the string and value to dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a comma separated string with values as follows:

```
"File_name,cost_per_page,0.23,color_code,343,thickness,0.01".
```

I want to read cost_per_page = 0.23, color_code=343 and thickness=0.01.

How can I do this? I could do this by putting it to a list and reading successive element next to key string. Is there any other method?

Comment: What will your treat with `File_name`?

Comment: You can do as you said, split the string to a string array and then you iterate through the array by reading the key and the value. I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and therefor, probably the best) approach would be to simply use `string.Split` and then iterate the array:

```
var source = "File_name,cost_per_page,0.23,color_code,343,thickness,0.01";

var splitted = source.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// Note: Starting from 1 to skip the "file_name"
// moving 2 indexes in each iteration, 
// and ending at length - 2.
for(int i = 1; i < splitted.Length - 1; i+=2)
{
    result.Add(splitted[i], splitted[i+1]);
}
```

I've tried to find a clever way to do it with linq, but the best I came up with is really not that clever at all:

```
var valuesWithIndexes = source
    .Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select((v, i) => new {v, i});

var keys = valuesWithIndexes.Where(x => x.i % 2 == 0);
var values = valuesWithIndexes.Where(x => x.i % 2 == 1);

var dictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new {k, v})
    .ToDictionary(key => key.k,
                  val => val.v);
```

I think the simple for loop is a clear winner in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the simplest and best approach.

```
string str = "File_name,cost_per_page,0.23,color_code,343,thickness,0.01";

string[] array = str.Split(',');
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i = i + 2)
{
    string key = array[i];
    double value = Double.Parse(array[i + 1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dict.Add(key, value);
}
```

You can also use the above code for a larger string (variable `str` has more *key-value* pairs).

Comment: How is that any different than the answer I've posted 7 minutes before you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use linq.
Convert the string into a delimited array.

Set up a dictionary containing the first item...not sure if you want to do this.  If not just remove the "d1" and "union" statements.

Run some Linq to create your dictionary based on even numbers.

Then if you really want to account for the first item, file_name, and you want that at the beginning of your dictionary then lastly you'd run the "union" statement.

```
string str = "File_name,cost_per_page,0.23,color_code,343,thickness,0.01";
string[] array = str.Split(',');

Dictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { array[0], "" }
};
Dictionary<string, string> d2 = array.Select((i, index) => (index > 0 && index % 2 == 0) ?
    new { key = array[index - 1], value = i } : null).Where(i => i != null).ToDictionary(d => d.key, d => d.value);

Dictionary<string, string> result = d1.Union(d2).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in result)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);

return;
```

another, and probably cleaner approach:

This accounts for File_name as well.  If you don't want it then add "index > 0" to the conditional operator where it checks for even.

```
string str = "File_name,cost_per_page,0.23,color_code,343,thickness,0.01";
string[] array = str.Split(',');

Dictionary<string, string> d2 = array.Select((i, index) => (index % 2 == 0) ?
    new 
    {
        key = (index == 0) ? i : array[index - 1],
        value = (index == 0) ? "" : i
    } : null).Where(i => i != null).ToDictionary(d => d.key, d => d.value);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in d2)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full working example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rbYMy).

All you need is to iterate while you haven't reached your string array end ensuring your index increments by 2 (field name, field value).

```
int i = 1;
var temp = s.Split(',').ToList();
while(i < temp.Count) {
    i = i+2;
}
```